# how to find which number has been entered the most consecutive times without arrays?

Tags: c, loops

ive recently started reading a book about C and came across this exercise. Make a program that reads 100 integers and outputs the number that has been entered the most consecutive times without the use of arrays. Now the way i solved this is probably the dumbest one there is. I basically "use an array" without having it be an actual array and i have to do everything the hard way. Is there a better way to do this without actual arrays? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    int zero, one, two, three ,four,
    five, six, seven, eight, nine;
    int i,j,num,prev = -1;
    
    
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=0;i<100;i++){
        num = rand()%10;
        printf("%d\n", num);
        if(num==prev){
            switch(num){
                case 0: zero++;
                case 1: one++;
                case 2: two++;
                case 3: three++;
                case 4: four++;
                case 5: five++;
                case 6: six++;
                case 7: seven++;
                case 8: eight++;
                case 9: nine++;
            }
        }
        prev = num;
    }
    
    num = 0;
    //comparing the number of times of each number
        if(num<zero){
         num=zero;
         j=0;
        }
        if(num<one){
        num=one;
        j=1;
        }
        if(num<two){
         num=two;
         j=2;
        }
        if(num<three){
         num=three;
         j=3;
        }
        if(num<four){
        num=four;
        j=4;
        }
        if(num<five){
         num=five;
         j=5;
        }
        if(num<six){
         num=six;
         j=6;
        }
        if(num<seven){
         num=seven;
         j=7;
        }
        if(num<eight){
         num=eight;
         j=8;
        }
        if(num<nine){
         num=nine;
         j=9;
        }
    printf("Number is %d", j);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you may be trying to solve the wrong problem - re-read the problem statement carefully. The solution will be much simpler than the code you have above.

Comment: Think about *"consecutive"* and current *"number"*. Consider using a `prev_number` variable to determine if the current input is the same as the last.

Comment: You will only need to have like 4 variables: (i) max consecutive frequency so far, (ii) the integer value which has the max consecutive frequency so far, (iii) the consecutive frequency of the 'current' number, (iv) the integer value of the 'current' number. After each input, need to change the state of these variablea based on some number comparison.

Comment: There are more integers that zero through nine!